# Disable commenting in blog

Tags: blog, 2007

Can't seem to find a way to easily disable commenting on a SharePoint Blog (I hope it's Blog, my SP isn't in English).

When I currently open the Post.aspx?ID=myPostID, I can add a comment to the post, even if I'm in the group with only reading permissions. Any suggestions or what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the permissions of the Comments list so nobody can place a comment. I think it has unique permissions on the site. 
That should keep people from posting.

Comment: I knew it had to be that easy, thanks! My logic just doesn't cope with SharePoint (yet) :)